# Python Regex: Match (Search) for List Elements in a Use-Input String and Action

Tags: python, regex, search

As part of a Python text game, I would like to use regex to search for elements from a List or Dictionary in a User-input string, and, if elements are matched, process various actions.

I've tried probably a dozen different version of regex code, and none have delivered exactly the results I'm looking for.

I've only used regex in very limited (data analytics) contexts before, and my grasp of its behavior is narrow. (I started with a simple split method, applied to the User-input string, which works fine in limited contexts, but, because the List elements can have varying lengths (e.g., 1 to 4 words), it quickly becomes infeasible to just use split without writing a dozen conditions specific to different List elements.)

The User-input string will follow a very predictable pattern, so this seems like a problem with a relatively straight-forward solution.

Output / Action Scenarios:

1. If [Inventory List Element] called in Use statement is in Inventory List, AND is 'useable' (see: Items Dictionary), print 'You use [Inventory List Element]'
2. If [Inventory List Element] called in Use statement is in Inventory List, AND is NOT 'useable' (as defined in an Items Dictionary), print 'Nothing happens that you can perceive.'
3. If [Inventory List Element] called in Use statement is not in Inventory List, print 'That item isn't in your inventory.'

The problem (well, one of them, anyways) that I'm encountering is that the regex Search iterates through each Item in the Inventory List, and returns a response; if I use a simple >> pass << to eliminate a response when no match is made, I can't call Scenario 3, which is that the Item called in the Use statement was not in the inventory.

For example, if the User-input statement is, 'use Pink Bunny on skeleton', and 'Pink Bunny' isn't in Inventory, then the loop just goes back to the beginning and asks the User what action they'd like to take.

I tried a re.findall statement, to create a list of re.search responses, and if all of the responses were 'None', run Scenario 3, but then I wasn't able to disaggregate the list to pick out the matching Item if the Use statement did include an Item in Inventory. (The code also got wonky even trying to call Scenario 3, to return 'That item isn't in your inventory.'.)

I figured out a (very) simple regex, below, that individually assesses whether the Item 'used' is in the inventory, and, as a separate for loop, assesses whether the Target is a legitimate target. See below. But, I haven't been able to pass the Item identified in the first for loop to the second (Target) for loop, to create a coherent statement, 'You used [Matched Item] on [Matched Target].' (The Target for loop takes the next Item in the Inventory list and plugs it in, which more or less make sense.)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated; each time I think I have a solution, I run into one last deal-breaker that I'm unable to resolve.

(Model) str = 'use [Inventory List Element] on [Target List Element]'

```
import re
    
inventory = ['Golden Cape', 'White Diamond Key', 'Carving Knife', 'Silver Long Sword', 'Citrine Key']
    
selected_action = 'use Pink Bunny on Black-Boned Skeleton'
    
def match(selected_action):
    for item in inventory:
        match = re.search(fr'use\s{item}', selected_action)
            if match:
                # print(match)
                # print(item)
                print(f'you use {item}')
            else:
                # pass
                print('no item')
    
    for target in targets_detail:
        match = re.search(fr'on\s{target}', selected_action)
            if match:
                # print(match)
                # print(target)
                print(f'you use {item} on {target}')
            else:
                # print('no target')
                pass
    
match(selected_action)


targets_detail = {
    'None':
        {
            'type': 'Enemy',
            'room': 'None',
            'available': 'No',
            'removed from room': 'True',
            'useable': 'No',
            'vulnerable to': 'None',
            'item descr':
                '''
        No item description.
                ''',
            'in-room descr':
                '''
        No other persons appear to be present.        
                ''',
            'creature death descr':
                '''
        No creature death description.
                ''',
            'player death descr':
                '''
        No Player death description.
                '''
        },
    'Frost Giant':
        {
            'type': 'Enemy',
            'room': 'Kitchen',
            'available': 'No',
            'removed from room': 'False',
            'useable': 'No',
            'vulnerable to': 'Lochaber Axe',
        },
    'Black-Boned Skeleton':
        {
            'type': 'Enemy',
            'room': 'North Parlor',
            'available': 'No',
            'removed from room': 'False',
            'useable': 'No',
            'vulnerable to': 'Silver Long Sword',
        },
    'Cabinet':
        {
            'type': 'Misc',
            'room': 'Library',
            'available': 'No',
            'removed from room': 'False',
            'useable': 'No',
            'vulnerable to': 'Silver Candelabra',
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware this is the general subject of tokenizing user input, and is fairly complex and fraught with perils and ambiguity!

That said, to get a better system and if you don't have too many items (say a few thousand - I show a certesian product to make every combination, but it's unlikely you really want this), I wouldn't directly use a regex for this (though they may be useful to extract and compare terms!), but consider a variety of techniques, especially [`difflib.get_close_matches()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_normalization) the input data

```py
import difflib
import itertools
import re

modifier_1 = {
    "black",
    "carving",
    "citrine",
    "golden",
    "pink",
    "silver",
    "white",
}
modifier_2 = {
    "",  # nothing - caution lazy
    "boned",
    "long",
}
names = {
    "bunny",
    "cape",
    "key",
    "knife",
    "skeleton",
    "sword",
}

collection = set(map(
    " ".join,
    itertools.product(modifier_1, modifier_2, names)
))

def check_use(data):
    data = data.lower().strip()
    # check for no data
    A, B = re.match("^use (.*) on (.*)$", data).groups()
    try:
        A = get_close_matches(A, collection)[0]
        B = get_close_matches(B, collection)[0]
    except IndexError:  # didn't find and match
        return None     # warn the user about their input
    return A, B
```

```py
>>> check_use("use Pink Bunny on Black-Boned Skeleton")
('pink  bunny', 'black boned skeleton')
>>> check_use("use White Key on golden long-sword")
('white  key', 'golden long sword')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I was hoping for a more streamlined solution, but I understand the limitations the open text entry imposes on tokenization. 

I’ll try a (simplified) version of your suggestion.